# Error NETSDK1136: The target platform must be set to Windows

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio-mac

I get this error message in Visual Studio for Mac 2022 17.3.8 (build 5) when I want to run my iOS project on my iPad:

/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.402/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.Shared.targets(5,5): Error NETSDK1136: The target platform must be set to Windows (usually by including '-windows' in the TargetFramework property) when using Windows Forms or WPF, or referencing projects or packages that do so.

But I don't know where this error comes from because I use net6.0-ios in my iOS csproj file and my SharedCode project doesn't seem to have a csproj file.

What is wrong with my iOS project? What should I change?

EDIT:
I get the error in this line in the file Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.Shared.targets:

```
    <NetSdkError Condition="'@(_WindowsDesktopTransitiveFrameworkReference)' != ''"
             ResourceName="WindowsDesktopTargetPlatformMustBeWindows" />
```

My dependencies in my iOS project:

[image: Dependencies picture]

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know Xamarin.CommunityToolkit uses WPF and caused the error in my project. It works for me to disable the error:

```
    <Target BeforeTargets="_CheckForTransitiveWindowsDesktopDependencies" Name="_FixSdkError_NETSDK1136">
        <ItemGroup>
            <TransitiveFrameworkReference Remove="Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App" />
            <TransitiveFrameworkReference Remove="Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WPF" />
            <TransitiveFrameworkReference Remove="Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WindowsForms" />
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>
```

Comment: Prism.Plugin.Popups is also one of these packages that (indirectly) reference WPF stuff.... The target you posted worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to run a WPF or WinForms application (or your application has a dependency on these) in Mac/iOS. You can't do that as WPF/Winforms are Windows only.

Try creating a Xamarin or MAUI app for a multiplatform solution.

Comment: Is it possible to find out if my iOS application has a dependency on these?

Comment: @harry_mitch Under your project, look at Dependencies. it will show the framework and packages being used.

Comment: How can I find out which dependency causes the problem? I can add a picture of my dependencies if you want.

Comment: I added a picture with my dependencies.

Comment: I found the problem. It is the NuGet package Plugin.MediaManager that causes the problem on iOS. But on Android I don't get the error.

Comment: I had the same after porting a project from Xamarin.Forms to MAUI with the package `Rg.Plugins.Popup` in version 2.1.0 even though NuGet say it's .netstandard 2.0

Comment: @Waescher how did you solve it? I'm having the same issue after migrating to MAUI.

Comment: It actually was `Rg.Plugins.Popup` and another package I had that referenced Xamarin.

Comment: how did you solve this @harry_mitch? i'm having the same issue with media manager

Comment: @clarky you can try my workaround (disable the error)

Answer (score 0):

In project file (.csproj) you have to definition OutputType (for example  Library). If not you got the error